# How to link projects in NetBeans and add to SVN?

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

I have to use NetBeans for a Java Web project.

I have 3 projects, 1 is the main project, the others are just small components. I added the two small ones to the main one (add jar or something...), which worked fine.
The main project is added to a SVN repo, but I want to commit all 3 projects at once when I commit the main project. I have seen a solution for this once in Eclipse, but cannot remember.
Currently, when i commit, only the main project is commited to SVN. I could add the other 2 separately, but I don't want to commit all components, one by one.
Does someone know how I can include the 2 projects to the main one in order to commit it as a whole to the svn repo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can select several projects, right click on them and press `Team > Commit...`, the commit window will let you commit all the selected projects

Comment: Check [this out](http://subclipse.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=783), it looks like they "fix it" back in 2008, you have to layout your repo kind of different from the usual layout though